# Fire 'object:moving' event from resetting position in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric.js and I'm looking to have the `canvas.on('object:moving')` event fired but not when a mouse drags it. I want to do it if I animate the position moving by itself. I could not achieve this by adding the listener and making `object.left -= 2`.

I added a jsFiddle for this. At first, you will be able to drag the circle and the line will follow. Then uncomment line 49 and watch the circle move and the line will stay still. 
http://jsfiddle.net/P5UJM/

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @kangax Well what's happening is, I have the canvas listener set to object:moving, and every frame I have a circle moving left. The event will not fire when it's moving each frame but the event will fire when the circle is dragged. How do I get the event to recognize it's moving when it is not dragged but moving on its own?

Comment: "object:moving" is only fired when dragging an object. Use "onchange" callback instead (when animating object's left).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot about the animation function. One more slight issue...animate() seems to stop & go instead of continuing. How do we create a continuous motion?

Comment: Not important but looking to know for future use. I cannot find documentation on it.

Comment: Take a look at http://fabricjs.com/clipping/